# SQLite efficient way to union tables and count(*)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to count the rows of two tables include using the where clause. I already got a solution, but don't know if this is the best way. The where clause is build dynamically and filters up to 5 columns. The table has got 10 columns and can have up to some million records.

```
select count(*) from 
(
select * from pending {whereClause} 
union all
select * from history {whereClause}
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the tables can have different indexes, and you may apply difference `WHERE` clauses, yours is a perfectly valid solution.

As there is an overhead in checking the signature of different sets, you may be faster to get the two counts separately, then add them up...

```
SELECT
  (select COUNT(*) from pending {whereClause})
  +
  (select COUNT(*) from history {whereClause})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `union all` is rather expensive with large amounts of data.  You might find that doing the counts independently is a little bit faster:

```
select p.cnt + h.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt from pending {whereClause}) p cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from history {whereClause}) h;
```

In addition, this opens the possibility of the query using only indexes for each subquery.  That could be a more significant performance gain.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! If you need to know the result of each table, this is a good way!